# Org export via org-ref-->pandoc, bibliography using relative path

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pandoc

Can org-ref export through ox-pandoc using a relative path to the bibliography file?

Export via **org --> pandoc --> HTML** succeeds when the org document contains an absolute path to the bib file. However using a path to the bib file relative to the org file directory, such as `bibliography:/bib/mybib.bib`, produces the error: `File ‘bib/mybib.bib’ not in paths defined via bibtex-file-path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed a fix to ox-word that should address this issue and make it possible to use relative paths.

Comment: Export to MS Word now works using a relative path. Note: In your fix to ox-word (June 6), I had to replace two instances of the variable `bibfiles` with `bibfile` in the function `ox-export-via-latex-pandoc-to-docx-and-open`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using org-ref. The syntax for using bibliographies with ox-pandoc and pandoc is different than for regular org export. 
add the following to your header:

```
#+Bibliography: ~/path/bibliography.bib
```

Comment: Original question updated to indicate the use case applies to org-ref.